# Loop through Named Ranges with Dates, Calculate difference on 3rd column

Tags: vba, date, excel, named-ranges

I have an Excel sheet that has 2 dynamic named range for user to input starting dates and ending dates.

I would like VBA to check that when user enter starting date and ending date, calculate the difference and have the result shown on 3rd column:

```
From        To             No of Days
01.05.15    03.05.15       3
02.05.15    05.05.15       4
```

If the next starting and ending date row is empty, stop the calculation.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having with doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Why on earth would you want to program this?

In cell C2 enter `=B2-A2+1` and format as a general number.